# Angular - How to pass information to a controller via the router?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dynamic, single-page-application

**Database Table:**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| ID | PARENT ID | TITLE           | URL                           |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | 0         | Programming     | programming                   |
-------------------------------------------------------------------- 
| 2  | 1         | Logic           | programming/logic             |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| 3  | 1         | Object-Oriented | programming/oop               |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| 4  | 2         | PROLOG          | programming/logic/prolog      | 
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| 5  | 2         | LISP            | programming/logic/lisp        |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| 6  | 3         | JAVA            | programming/oop/java          |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| 7  | 3         | C#              | programming/oop/csharp        |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

**Page Setup:**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <nav ng-controller="navController">
            <ul ng-repeat="menuItem in menuItems">
                <li><a href="#/{{menuItem.URL}}">{{menuItem.Title}}</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <div ng-view>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

**Explanation:**

My navigation menu is derived from a database query, with drill-in navigation that only shows one level at a time.

The first level only displays one menu item:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#/programming">Programming</a>
    </li>
<ul>
```

If I click the "Programming" link, the navigation will now display that menu item's children:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#/programming/logic">Logic</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#/programming/object-oriented">Object-Oriented</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

---

**Assumptions:**

(1) Assume each of these menu items has a corresponding partial. For example, the "Object-Oriented" menu item has a corresponding partial at: "/partials/objectoriented.html".

(2) Assume I have a function GetMenuItemsByUrl(url) that will return to me all the children of a menu item based on its url. So for example, if I pass the url "programming/logic" the function will return me all the children of row 2, those beings rows 4 and 5. This function can be accessed via /api/GetMenuItemsByUrl/:url

---

**Expected Behavior:**

Assume the user enters the following url:
mywebsite.com/#/programing

(1) The nav should render as such:

- Logic
- Object-Oriented

(2) The view should load the template: /templates/programming.html

---

**Question:**

I know how to render the view based on the route via the router. My question is, how do I also pass the current url to the navController and tell it to rebind?

Comment: Create a service that keeps track of the current menu? It'll be updated automatically in your navController since a service is a singleton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the example I made based on my understanding of your issue [jsbin link](http://jsbin.com/uSABApi/32/edit?html,js,output)

To achieve infinite nesting of the routes you could create a catch all route with

```
$routeProvider
.when('/:url*', {templateUrl: function(args) {
    return 'programming.tpl.html';
}, controller:'NavController'});
```

This will get the whole url as a param which could be passed to a controller as $routeParams.url property.

```
 app.controller('NavController', function($scope, $routeParams, MenuService) {
    $scope.menuItems = MenuService.getMenuItems($routeParams.url);
    ...
 }
```

And `MenuService` should handle all the logic behind getting the menu items from the url.

Example is pretty simple and has limited functionality regarding validation and url to items mapping. Feel free to ask more specific questions.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the example! What if the page wasn't just a static template, but also required a controller of its own? I guess the essence of my question is then, based on a single route, how do I pass information to two separate, non-nested controllers? Sorry, I am very new to Angular and am having difficult formulating my question.

Comment: "What if the page wasn't just a static template, but also required a controller of its own? "
A controller could be added to a template wither in the template itself with a `ng-controller` directive or in the `.when` definition of a state. A separate controllers should not be created as only the menu items are different. So you could use a single controller which will receive the menu items as params and change it's behavior according to those params.

Comment: "how do I pass information to two separate, non-nested controllers"
Via a separated service created with a `.factory` or `.service` methonds. You can inject a `$routeParams` service to all the controllers you need. All of them will access the data. In case you need to share a custom data you should create a storage service, put that data there and inject it into your controllers

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you need to use $routeParams in your controller.

Markup:

```
<a href="#/route/{{vm.org.id}}" class="btn btn-success">
```

RouteProvider Configuration:

```
url: '/route/:id
```

in your controller:

```
var routeId = $routeParams.id
```

Comment: I tried this but my controller is not rebinding when I change the route, only when I load the app for the first time.